# Mean squared error computed by TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, mean-square-error

I am trying to figure out how the mean squared error (MSE) is calculated by `tensorflow` and was reading the post at https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/mean_squared_error.

First of all, MSE is defined as (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error):

[image]

Suppose I have a single output and create true and predicted values.

```
import numpy as np
import random

y_true = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(2, 1))
print(y_true,"\n")
y_pred = np.random.randint(0,5,size=(2, 1))
print(y_pred)

[[7]
 [5]]

[[2]
 [2]]
```

When I call `tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)`, what I expect to see is that `[(7-2)^2 + (5-2)^2]/2 = 17`, however, it returns me `array([25,  9])`. Why doesn't tensorflow compute the mean?

Then, I increase the column numbers.

```
y_true = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(2, 3))
print(y_true,"\n")
y_pred = np.random.randint(0,5,size=(2, 3))
print(y_pred)

[[2 6 0]
 [3 3 4]] 

[[4 2 4]
 [3 4 2]]
```

The answer returned by `tensorflow` is `array([12,  1])`. I'm not able to understand how these values are computed. What I was expecting was `[(2-4)^2+ (6-2)^2+(0-4)^2]/2 + [(3-3)^2 + (3-4)^2+ (4-2)^2]/2` .

Comment: Have you examined the tensorflow code?  What don't you understand.  This site is best used once you have a specific problem that you can't figure out, general questions asking for guidance doesn't fit with SO's objectives.

Comment: No, I have not, I decided to ask this question randomly out of the blue (!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second value is computed as

```
a = np.array([2,6,0])
b = np.array([4,2,4])
((b - a)**2).mean()
```

Or `[(2-4)^2+ (6-2)^2+(0-4)^2]/3`

According to their [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/mean_squared_error) it is equivalent to `np.mean(np.square(y_true - y_pred), axis=-1)`

So it is computing the mse row-wise.

Comment: Okay, but then how does the second row is computed? It should return ````5/3````

Comment: I think it is because you are using integers

Comment: So If I am training a network with integers, I have to convert everything to float to get the correct results?

Comment: well I think so. Why do you want to train a NN with integers?

Comment: Well my parameters are integers and the output is an integer too.

Comment: In that case, if I am guessing correctly it is indeed the dtype issue, it is best to come up with your customized loss function

Comment: Great, thanks for the explanation and heads up.